# Installing Ruby offline using rvm

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, offline

I need to install Ruby-1.9.2 in an offline machine using rvm. I tried by copying ruby-1.9.2-p180.tar.gz in to ./rvm/archives and running  rvm install ruby-1.9.2. But still rvm is trying to download Ruby from ftp.ruby-lang.org'. Any advice is greatly appreciated...

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but even once RVM has installed ruby itself, it installs a whole bunch of "standard" gems, so you may end up jumping through hoops to get it all working properly.

Comment: rvm is open source. Worst comes to worse, I'm sure you can go through the code and comment out the lines which perform the download. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm

Comment: Is it an old version of rvm? It's default version of 1.9.2 could differ from patch level 180. Try `rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p180`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but the best place to get rvm support is just to hop on IRC and check out the #rvm channel on Freenode. The maintainer, wayneeseguin is very responsive, generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, where I want to deploy the ruby version and all associated gems to the production machines...

I would highly recommend that you use either "rsync' or 'scp -rp' to **copy the complete subdirectory ~/.rvm to the target machine**. If that machine is completely offline, you could of course copy that directory with 'cp -rp' to a flash-drive and then copy it to the non-networked machine.

One important Gotcha:

**be sure that you use the identically named user account on all machines, if you replicate the .rvm directory!**

I noticed that the internal book-keeping of RVM keeps track of some environment variables during installation of Ruby versions and gems, and that it keeps track in particular of the name of the user account that was used, and the path to the users's home directory.   Beats me why they don't use $HOME and $USER , which are standard on all UNIXes.. seems like a real bug in RVM to me.

if you use the same user account for all machines, it will work just fine.