# Correct way to set up Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Thanks Tilo for your response.  I will try to ask a better question.

I need to set up a Ruby on Rails Production environment that will only be used to host RoR applications and will be used as a Git server too.  There will be no development done to these applications on the Production server.  Right now, I forsee the production server hosting a maximum of 5 to 6 applications only.  A couple will be company internal only and the rest of the apps will be viewable to the public.  The traffic that they will receive is about 12 to 20 hits per week.

I have been given access to a Virtual Machine that will be the Production server and is currently running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Apache2, MySQL, and Passenger.  There will be two RoR developers using the Production server to host their applications.

My Development Environment of which I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Apache2, and MySQL on my own laptop looks like this for each project/application:

- RVM installed per application, Git,
  Ruby 1.9.2 installed thru rvm, Rails
  3.0.3, and I have yet to install the Capistrano gem.

My question is I don't understand how to host a RoR application on our production server.

As an example of what might be done to host a RoR application: I am surmising that I will create a user called app1 under the home directory.  Next, should I install Ruby system wide or should I install rvm for app1 and then Ruby for app1?  What are the steps involved on how to set-up the environment to run an application on a production server?

Can you give me a few setup scenarios, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what you want to use this web-site for... is it company internal only? 
just a few users? or is it externally facing the internet?  Just one server running everything?

If it's facing the internet, I would certainly stay away from Ubuntu... look at CentOS/RedHat or FreeBSD to install on a production server.

I'd definitely use Capistrano for deployment. Definitely Git.

I would definitely not install RVM system-wide - IMHO it is not robust enough.

I emailed with Wayne Seguin (maker of RVM) and he also uses the method I've outlined in the post below,
using one dedicated deploy user:

For how to deploy ruby-versions and gems with RVM, look at this post:
[Installing Ruby offline using rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919591/installing-ruby-offline-using-rvm)

If you really need two versions of Ruby for two different apps, then use two deploy-users!
Each of them has their own default-ruby-version(!) that's why you really need two users :)
and you can install / manage the gems for each project separately under each of the deploy accounts.
You should also put the git repository in each of the accounts, so you can test.